# How to set my own ViewController class as the first screen (root view)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have created a windows based project in XCode using IPhone as target platform and then I added a ViewController Sub Class. Now I want to make my newly added class to be shown at first screen. What is the proper way to achieve it?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct way i found

first declare your view controller in appdelegate.h

```
SaveViewController *SaveController;
```

also

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) SaveViewController * SaveController;
```

then synthesize it in your appdelegate.m file

```
@synthesize SaveController;
```

now add the following lines of code in your application didFinishLaunching Method

```
SaveController = [[SaveViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SaveViewController" bundle:nil];

[window addSubview:[SaveController view]];


[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Thats all.. you are done :)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your appdelegate, you'll find something like this:

```
[window addSubview:myView];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Change my view to the view you want to show first.

Comment: can you plz tell me what i am doing wrong. I put [window addSubview:[SaveViewController view]]; in application didfinishlaunching. SaveViewController is my XIB file name. Am I doing wrong or right ?

Comment: Here's a step by step guide, if you have problems, add a comment :) http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/example-of-window-base-application-in-iphone/

Comment: I also followed the same then i posted below :) Thanks for sharing link also :)