# App start from delegate viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, launch, appdelegate

I have four UIViewController for displays different purpose. If i launch the app it displays Delegate function. If i go to second or third viewcontroller then close the app. Again open the app, it displays third or second viewcontroller. I need to start app from delegate. How to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set my own ViewController class as the first screen (root view)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351510/how-to-set-my-own-viewcontroller-class-as-the-first-screen-root-view)

Comment: close the app in the sense you are deleting the instance of the application right?>

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller? Give some additional details. Have you tried anything to reset back to your 'root view controller'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plist file add one more field

Application does not run in background : make it true

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just pop your navigationcontroller to root view in your *applicationDidBecomeActive* method.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [navigationCtrl popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```